# If we double the input for 7*n^3

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I have a running time of 7*n<sup>3</sup>.

If we then double the input size for the algorithm how much slower will it be?

It is supposed to be 8 times slower. But I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we check with n=1 and n=2, you can see that the time doubles 8 times.

`7*1^3=7`

`7*2^3=7*8=56`

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward! Just double the input size from `n` to `2n`. Hence the running time relative to `n` is `7 * (2n)^3 = 7 * 8 * n^3 = 8 T(n)`, that `T(n) = 7 * n^3`.